# React Native: Redux - Is it possible to dispatch to redux store from App.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-reducers

I am working on a react native app and I have everything hooked up to a redux store so that I can manage data in that way.

I am curious about the possibility of dispatching data from the `App.js` component which at the moment I use to essentially route my app. The use case would be to make an API call in `App.js` and set data in redux store from there so that the app presumably makes that call every time it is opened. I know componentDidMount for instance runs the code once when the app is opened but then never again unless its closed and reopened. I assume that `App.js` might be better for something like this. If that assumption is incorrect my apologies as I am still learning.

In the example below, how would I run `callApi` and `setData` from `App.js` to the Redux Store if that is possible? Or should I avoid this an try to set a global variable?

Below is sample code:

**App.js**

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs'
    import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore } from 'redux';
    
    import ourReducer from './store/reducer';
    const store = createStore(ourReducer);
    global.x = 'https://volleybuddy.metis-data.site'
    
    
    import Home from './components/Home'
    import Profile from './components/Profile'
    import Login from './components/Login'
    import SignUp from './components/SignUp'
    import StartScreen from './components/StartScreen'
    
    export default class App extends Component {
    
    
      render(){
    
        return (
          
          <Provider store={ store }>
            <AppContainer/>
          </Provider>
        );
        }
    }
    
    const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: Home,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <Ionicons  name="ios-home" size={25} color={tintColor}/>
              // <Icon name="qrcode" size={25} color={tintColor} />
            )
          }
        },
        Profile: {
          screen: Profile,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              // <Icon name="search" size={25} color={tintColor} />
              <Ionicons  name="md-person" size={25} color={tintColor}/>
            )
          }
        },
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: '#eb6e3d'
        }
      }
    );
    
    const RootSwitch = createSwitchNavigator({ 
      StartScreen,
      SignUp,
      Login,
      bottomTabNavigator
      });
    
    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootSwitch);
```

**Reducer.js** (I set up my reducer something like this)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: null
};

const ourReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    const newState = { ...state };

  switch (action.type) {
        
                    case "SET_DATA":
                      return{
                        ...state,
                        data: action.value
                      }
                    break;
  
  }
  return newState;
};


export default combineReducers({
  reducer: ourReducer,
});
```

**Home.js** (Lets just say if I want to move callApi to run also in App.js)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Home extends Component {

    //NOT REAL CODE, JUST CONCEPT
    callApi =() => {
        fetch(....)
        let data = response
        this.props.setData(data)
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <View>
                <Button onPress={this.callApi}>
                    <Text>toggle tracking</Text>
                </Button>
            </View>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    
    const { reducer } = state
    return { reducer }
  };

  const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      setData: (x) => dispatch({ type: "SET_DATA", value: x}),
    };
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps,
    mapDispachToProps
    )(Home)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible.

I have a store.js file like this:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const middleware =  applyMiddleware(thunk)
const store = createStore(reducer,middleware)



export default store;
```

So, in the App.js file I just need to import the store like this:

```
import store from './src/store'
```

And you can call to dispatch:

```
 store.dispatch({ type: "ACTION_EXAMPLE" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch data from anywhere in the app as long as you can get a reference to the store using `store.dispatch`, in this case you can dispatch and action App component after the store is instantiated, but the App component itself is not connected to the store so it unable to re-render in response to changes on it, but this should not be a problem for you in this case.